# LinqToSql - .Contains on multi-column primary key from an in-memory list containing the primary keys

Tags: vb.net, linq, t-sql, contains

On a client i have an anonymous list containing a multi-column primary key previously selected from the DB.

Then i need to select all the records from the DB that equals the primary key list i have stored in the memory.

I think the below (simplified) example will give you an idea of what i am trying to archive and as you can see i already found a way, but i was hoping somebody had a better solution? :-)

*.NET example:*

```
Sub findKeys()
    Dim clientLst As New List(Of PriKeys)
    clientLst.Add(New PriKeys With {.p = 1, .i = 2})
    clientLst.Add(New PriKeys With {.p = 3, .i = 1})
    Using DC As New LTSQDataContext
        Dim p_lst = clientLst.Select(Function(x) x.p).ToList
        Dim i_lst = clientLst.Select(Function(x) x.i).ToList
        Dim concLst As New List(Of String) ' used for example 2/3
        clientLst.ForEach(Sub(v) concLst.Add(v.p & "|" & v.i))

        '1:  Wrong - returns row 1,1 (just had to try)
        Dim try1 = (From q In DC.TestTbl1s
                    Where p_lst.Contains(q.p) AndAlso i_lst.Contains(q.i)
                    Select q.p, q.i).ToList

        '2: Works! - but extremely slow as you can imagine
        Dim try2 = (From q In DC.TestTbl1s
                    Where concLst.Contains(q.p & "|" & q.i)
                    Select q).ToList

        '3: Works! - much faster that example 2, but requires double DB call, and returns unnecessary data. 
        Dim try3tmp = (From q In DC.TestTbl1s
                    Where p_lst.Contains(q.p)
                    Select q).ToList
        Dim try3 = (From q In try3tmp
                    Where concLst.Contains(q.p & "|" & q.i)
                   Select q).ToList

        '4: Any better solutions ???
    End Using
End Sub
Class PriKeys   'Class to hold the clients primary key collection
    Private _p As Integer
    Public Property p() As Integer
        Get
            Return _p
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _p = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _i As Integer
    Public Property i() As Integer
        Get
            Return _i
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _i = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

*SQL test data:*

```
CREATE TABLE TestTbl1 (p int, i int)
INSERT INTO TestTbl1 VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO TestTbl1 VALUES(1,2)
INSERT INTO TestTbl1 VALUES(1,3)
INSERT INTO TestTbl1 VALUES(2,1)
INSERT INTO TestTbl1 VALUES(3,1)
```

*(i apologize if an SO solution for this particular issue has been posted, i just couldn't find it/or understand it)*

Answer (score 0):

When I've had dynamic where statements like this I've used LINQkit with great success.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

You want to check out the predicate builder.